# Type XXX is not assignable to type 'EmailFieldProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

***EmailField.tsx***

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
    import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
    import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
    import EmailOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailOutlined';

    export interface EmailFieldProps {
      email: { text: string; err: string };
      setEmail: (props: { text: string; err: string }) => void;
      textFieldVariant?: "outlined" | "filled" | "standard";
      loading: boolean;
    }

    const EmailField: React.FC<EmailFieldProps> = ({
      email,
      setEmail,
      textFieldVariant = "filled",
      loading,
    }) => {
      return (
        <FormControl
        fullWidth
        margin="none"
        error={Boolean(email.err)}>
          <TextField
            placeholder={textFieldVariant === "outlined" ? "Email" : ""}
            label={textFieldVariant !== "outlined" && "Email"}
            error={Boolean(email.err)}
            variant={textFieldVariant}
            value={email.text}
            disabled={loading}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail({ text: e.target.value, err: "" });
            }}
            type={"email"}
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: textFieldVariant === "outlined" && (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <EmailOutlinedIcon color={email.err ? "error" : "action"} />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
          <FormHelperText>{email.err || " "}</FormHelperText>
             </FormControl>
      );
    };
    export default EmailField;
```

***SignIn.tsx***

```
     import React, {useState} from 'react'
             import FormControl from "@material-                                                      ui/core/FormControl";
             import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
             import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
             import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
             import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
             import EmailField from "components/Welcome/Fields/EmailField";
             import PasswordField from                "components/Welcome/Fields/PasswordField";
import {Link} from '@reach/router';
import {auth, signInWithGoogle} from "db/index";
import DashboardPage from 'pages/DashboardPage';


      const Google = {
    icon: () => (
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1004px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"
        width={20}
        height={20} />
     ),
};


export interface SignInProps {
  handleSignIn: (signInVars: { email: string; password: string }) => any;
  hideTabs?: boolean;
  handleSocial: {
    Google?: () => void;
  };
  textFieldVariant?: "outlined" | "filled" | "standard";
  emailValidator?: (value: string) => boolean;
  passwordValidator?: (value: string) => boolean;
}

interface NaviProps {
  goToForget: () => any;
  goToSignUp: () => any;
}


const SignIn: React.FC<SignInProps & NaviProps> = ({
  goToForget,
  handleSignIn,
  goToSignUp,
  handleSocial,
  hideTabs = false,
  textFieldVariant = "filled",
  emailValidator = (e) => !!e,
  passwordValidator = (e) => !!e,
}) => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);



  const handleSubmit =  (event: any) => {
                               const {name, value} = event.currentTarget;

                               if(name === 'userEmail')
                                   setEmail(value);
                               else if(name === 'userPassword')
                                   setPassword(value);
                           }

       const signInWithEmailAndPasswordHandler = (event :any, email: any, password: any) => {
             event.preventDefault();
             auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
             .then(() =>{
                 alert('Success')
             })
             .catch(() => {
                 if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                   console.log('That email address is already in use!');
                 }
                 if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                       console.log('That email address is invalid!');
                     }

                 console.error(error);
               });
         }

  return (
    <Box p={2}>
      <EmailField {...{ email, setEmail, textFieldVariant, loading }} />
      <PasswordField {...{ password, setPassword, textFieldVariant , loading }}/>
      <Typography
        variant="body2"
        color="textSecondary"
        align="right"
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={goToForget} >
        Forget Password?
      </Typography>

      <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
        <Button
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
          size="large"
          disabled={loading}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth >
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </FormControl>

      {Object.values(handleSocial).some((v) => typeof v === "function") && (
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
          or continue with
        </Typography>
      )}
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
            <IconButton
              aria-label={` login button`}
              onClick={()=> signInWithGoogle()}>
             {React.createElement(Google.icon, {
                //htmlColor: Social[key].color,
              })}
            </IconButton>

      </Box>
      {hideTabs && (
        <Typography
          variant="body2"
          color="textSecondary"
          align="center"
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={goToSignUp} >
          No Account? Create Now
        </Typography>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};
export default SignIn;
```

**ERROR:** Type '{ email: string; setEmail: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; textFieldVariant: "outlined" | "filled" | "standard"; loading: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'EmailFieldProps'.
Types of property 'email' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; err: string; }'.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the props as:

```
<EmailField 
  email={email} // <-- Error is here
  setEmail={setEmail} 
  textFieldVariant={textFieldVariant} 
  loading={loading} 
/>
```

The problem is in the `email` you are passing in - it should be an object with shape `{ text, err }` as you specified in `EmailFieldProps`.